# wordpress how do I add a metaphor icon

Tags: wordpress, icons, wordpress-theming, shortcode

I am working on a new wordpress theme that uses metaphor icons.
How can I add a new icon of my own using shortcodes as it will be cleaner than an over state.
Where is the page of icons located & can I add to it?

TIA Rich

Comment: You're unnamed theme uses them, how are we supposed to guess which theme it is? Probably somewhere in your themes folder.

Comment: Ok, I thought it may have been more general but it's the domino theme @ http://themeforest.net/item/domino-responsive-wordpress-theme/6079796?WT.ac=item_more_thumb&WT.seg_1=item_more_thumb&WT.z_author=digitalscience